# Can I call methods from another component in Vue3?

Tags: vuejs3

All I want to do is call the method 'updateCart()' in cart.vue from the component addtocart.vue. This method updates the cart by Axios.

I've seen the this.$root.$emit and $on methods but these are not working in Vue 3.

All the previous articles are outdated. Can someone help me?

**cart.vue**

```
<script>
export default {
    name: "cart",
    data() {
        return {
            items:  [],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updateCart() {
            //Axios get
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

**addtocart.vue**

```
<script>
export default {
    name: "Add to Cart",
    methods: {
        addToCart() {
            //Axios post 
            
            //Call function on cart.vue
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

**App.js**

```
/*-------------------------------------------
|   Vue
 ------------------------------------------*/
import {createApp} from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler';
import addtocart from './components/shop/addtocart.vue';
import cart from './components/shop/cart.vue';

/**
 * Shop
 */
const shopcart = createApp({
    components: {
        'cart': cart,
    },
},);
const shopapp = createApp({
    components: {
        'add-to-cart': addtocart,
    },
},);

/**
 * Mount
 */
shopapp.mount('#shop-app');
shopcart.mount('#shop-cart');
```

Comment: Check `defineExpose`, composition API is closing the methods by default. Also please provide the structure/some code snippets. Hard to help further as of right now.

Comment: I've edited the post to show the structure. The addtocart.vue first posts with Axios to add to the database and then I would like to update the cart in the top screen. I don't see how 'defineExpose' works here?

Comment: You're not using Composition API here so it's unrelated. Still, I don't see how they are structured here. Usually you use props + emits in a parent/child relation ship. If they are too far, you may use a store like Vuex or Pinia.

Comment: I'm sorry, the app.js is added. I'm using Vite with Laravel 9 and Vue 3. There are 2 mounted area's with 2 components as you can see in the app.js.

Comment: well if you mount 2 apps there is no way your components could communicate with each other. Except by using a store like pinia as suggested by @kissu.

Comment: But before learning how a store works, I strongly recommend you to follow a course about vue 3, there is a lot of good videos on youtube. Looking at your code it seems that you can code but you lack some basic concept about vue

Comment: Thank you for all the help! It's true i'm new to Vue but I have to start somewhere. First I tried Pinia what worked fine. In the Pinia docs it said it is pretty heavy for less than 5-10 components. Then I spotted the AlpineJS store function (Alpine is pre-installed in Laravel now) and it can be used within Vue scripts, just with Alpine.store('cart').items[]. AlpineJS is very fast, lightweight and easy to learn so I go with that I think.

Comment: You also have petite vue: https://github.com/vuejs/petite-vue